# Can I use '<' and '>' in match?

Tags: rust, match, quadratic

I am trying to do a simple quadratic function that would return number of roots and their values via an enum:

```
enum QuadraticResult {
    None,
    OneRoot(f32),
    TwoRoots(f32, f32),
}

fn solveQuadratic(a: f32, b: f32, c: f32) -> QuadraticResult {
    let delta = b * b - 4.0 * a * c;
    match delta {
        < 0 => return QuadraticResult::None,
        > 0 => return QuadraticResult::TwoRoots(0.0, 1.0),
        _ => return QuadraticResult::OneRoot(0.0),
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile as it complains about '<' and '>'. Is there a way to achieve this with `match` or do I need to use `if`

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for identifiers. `solve_quadratic` not `solveQuadratic`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Good point. Luckily rls plugin for Visual Studio Code flagged this for me as well after I was able to compile it. :)

Comment: I suppose you're eventually going to replace `0.0` and `1.0` with calculated values. Be careful not to assume that, when `QuadraticResult::TwoRoots(x, y)` is returned, `x != y`. Even if `d` is greater than 0, `-b + d.sqrt()` and `-b - d.sqrt()` may still be the same. [Here's an easy example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f739a13470238a96374b0b8826b82a88&version=stable), but it could happen with finite roots too. You may want to return `Option<(x1, x2)>` and let the caller decide whether `x1` and `x2` are "close enough" to be considered a single root.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use a [match guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/book/patterns.html#guards), but that feels more verbose than a plain `if` statement:

```
return match delta {
    d if d < 0 => QuadraticResult::None,
    d if d > 0 => QuadraticResult::TwoRoots(0.0, 1.0),
    _   => QuadraticResult::OneRoot(0.0),
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that I definitely prefer 'match' than 'if/else' statements in this case as the code looks much neater and readable IMHO.

Comment: Another thing came to mind. Is there any obvious performance difference between 'if/else' and 'match'?

Comment: @dawid even if you will have any difference in performance - it will be not guarantee to stay the same on next version. You shouldn't bother about performance at this level if you aren't force to do. First is readability - optimization is compiler work. [Here you can check assemble code of match and if](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/ZBZzRx)

Answer (score 30):

If you want to handle the three cases where some value is greater than, equal to or less than another, you can match on an `Ordering`, which you can obtain by calling [`cmp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#tymethod.cmp) (from the [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) trait) or [`partial_cmp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html#tymethod.partial_cmp) (from the [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) trait).

```
fn solve_quadratic(a: f32, b: f32, c: f32) -> QuadraticResult {
    let delta = b * b - 4.0 * a * c;
    match delta.partial_cmp(&0.0).expect("I don't like NaNs") {
        Ordering::Less => QuadraticResult::None,
        Ordering::Greater => QuadraticResult::TwoRoots(0.0, 1.0),
        Ordering::Equal => QuadraticResult::OneRoot(0.0),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

[You can](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e4886743eea194d9777c0d0cae00763a&version=stable), but you'll want to create a variable binding when you do it and turn it into an actual expression:

```
match delta {
    d if d < 0.0 => QuadraticResult::None,
    d if d > 0.0 => QuadraticResult::TwoRoots(0.0, 1.0),
    _ => QuadraticResult::OneRoot(0.0),
}
```

I'm not sure this is any better than just splitting this into an `if` statement though.

Comment: Thank you Simon. I will have to accept Jacob's answer as he was first :)

Comment: Oh no problem at all. I didn't see Jacobs answer ... hah, they're nearly identical too! I may as well remove mine.

Answer (score 1):

> #### Warning: as of rustc 1.67.0 (fc594f156 2023-01-24) this method still works, but will stop working [for float literals](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41620) in a future release.

You can use a [Range Pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#range-patterns) which are supported in [match expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html). This requires the `exclusive_range_pattern` feature.

```rust
#![feature(exclusive_range_pattern)]
fn solveQuadratic(a: f32, b: f32, c: f32) -> QuadraticResult {
    let delta = b * b - 4.0 * a * c;
    match delta {
        std::f32::MIN..0.0 => return QuadraticResult::None,
        0.0 => return QuadraticResult::OneRoot(0.0),
        _ => return QuadraticResult::TwoRoots(0.0, 1.0),
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=71ef5e37510665a2a8f0d0ec7aed7492)